# Better way to extract data with python regex from strings

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the reviews number (digit) from a string with python regex. The code works, however very long as I have added and if, else statement for each eventuality by slightly modifying the regex formula.
Is there a better way to do it so to use a single formula, rather than changing constantly formula for each eventuality?

Here is my code?

```
import re
# This below is the list containing the tuples with the data I want to extract from.

data_tup = [('B079T2F3CY', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Poster Inspired Watercolor Wall Art Jedi Yoda Death Star Prints Decor Paper Set of 6 8x10 P49 by PGbureau4.8 out of 5 stars16$24.99$24.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates"),
('B01A0NB55A', 'Star Wars Mug, Lightsabers Appear With Heat (12 oz)4.3 out of 5 stars948$9.99$9.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$6.91(2 used & new offers)'),
('B00VF18WWG', 'Star Wars: The Phantom MenaceMPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)|Closed Caption4.2 out of 5 stars3,037Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Liam Neeson,Ewan McGregor,Natalie PortmanandJake LloydDirected by:George LucasRuntime:136 minutes'),
('B00KRIR2HY', "Star Wars Men's Words Of Wisdom T-Shirt4.6 out of 5 stars372$11.00$11.00-$25.99$25.99"),
('B07CFYL578', 'VTech Star Wars First Order Stormtrooper Smartwatch4.2 out of 5 stars191$53.48$53.48Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$30.45(5 used & new offers)Ages: 5 - 9 years'),
('B077T5MG5F', 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'),
('B079T2F3CY', 'Star Wars Poster Inspired Watercolor Wall Art Jedi Yoda Death Star Prints Decor Paper Set of 6 8x10 P49 by PGbureau4.8 out of 5 stars16$24.99$24.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B00VF0M7QE', 'Star Wars: Return of the Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)|Closed Caption4.5 out of 5 stars1,055Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Mark Hamill,Harrison Ford,Carrie Fisher, et al.Directed by:Richard MarquandRuntime:134 minutes'),
('B01J5GKX60', 'Star Wars Classic Space Battle Full Sheet Set4.5 out of 5 stars53$34.99$34.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 2 left in stock - order soon.More Buying Choices$26.99(3 new offers)'),
('B079MB31DY', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Enjoy The Wood Star Wars Music Box Wooden Star Wars Fans Custom Gift for Boyfriend Gift for Brother4.9 out of 5 stars22$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates"),
('B00ZYXVU7K', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Lightsaber Heat Change Mug4.1 out of 5 stars158$13.95$13.95Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 9 left in stock - order soon."),
('B014HPF5G2', 'Hasbro Gaming Star Wars Bop It Game4.7 out of 5 stars446$14.99$14.99$16.99$16.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$7.99(16 used & new offers)Ages: 8 years and up'),
('B00VN0DLRA', 'Star Wars: A New HopeMPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance  Suggested)|Closed Caption4.5 out of 5 stars2,226Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Mark Hamill,Harrison Ford,Carrie FisherandPeter CushingDirected by:George LucasRuntime:124 minutes'),
('B079MB31DY', 'Enjoy The Wood Star Wars Music Box Wooden Star Wars Fans Custom Gift for Boyfriend Gift for Brother4.9 out of 5 stars22$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B076FDK9TF', 'Lenovo Star Wars: Jedi Challenges, Smartphone Powered Augmented Reality ExperienceDec 1, 2017|by Lenovo4.0 out of 5 stars102iOS$64.99$64.99$99.99$99.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$35.99(35 used & new offers)'),
('B015NFSC24', "Star Wars Classic Logo and Tie Fighter Men's Short Sleeve T-Shirt4.8 out of 5 stars52$15.89$15.89-$19.99$19.99"),
('B013GTX6JI', 'Star Wars - The Complete Saga Episodes I-VI4.5 out of 5 stars6,958Blu-ray$78.49$78.49More Buying Choices$45.99(26 used & new offers)DVD$43.93$43.93In stock on August 30, 2019.More Buying Choices$43.00(11 used & new offers)'),
('B013C1JLLM', 'Star Wars Episode VII Plastic Table Cover, Party Favor4.5 out of 5 stars8More Buying Choices$1.59(16 new offers)Ages: 36 months - 15 years'),
('0440418410', 'The Boys Start the War (Boy/Girl Battle)byPhyllis Reynolds Naylor|Jan 8, 20024.2 out of 5 stars37Paperback$6.99$6.99More Buying Choices$0.10(122 used & new offers)Kindle$6.99$6.99Library Binding$17.80$17.80Only 3 left in stock (more on the way).More Buying Choices$5.62(47 used & new offers)'),
('B00CLS39UM', 'SponsoredThese are ads for products you\'ll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product\'s page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars"Who\'s Your Daddy"? Father\'s Day Coffee Mug Collectible Novelty 11 Oz Nice Valentine Inspirational and Motivational Souvenir4.7 out of 5 stars143$10.99$10.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B018SAMUE2', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Grid Mug of Episode VII + 4 Free Bonus The Force Awakens Stickers4.1 out of 5 stars3$14.99$14.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 12 left in stock - order soon."),
('B00O0TE4MC', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Classic 63” Drapery /Curtain 4pc Set (2 Panels, 2 Tie backs) - R2D2, C3PO, Chewbacca, Darth Vader, Stormtrooper - Official Star Wars Product4.5 out of 5 stars168$13.01$13.01$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates")]

# This is the actual function that I am currently using:

def reviews_extractor(data):
    reviews = re.findall("[stars][\d,]+\$",data[1]) 
    if reviews == []:
        reviews = re.findall("[s][\W\d,]+[P]", data[1])
        if reviews == []:
            reviews = re.findall("[s][\W\d,]+[i]", data[1])
            if reviews == []:
                reviews = re.findall("[s][\W\d,]+[B]", data[1])
                if reviews == []:
                    reviews = re.findall("[s][\W\d,]+[M]", data[1])
                    if reviews == []:
                        print('Empty')
                    else:
                        print(reviews[0][1:-1])
                else:
                    print(reviews[0][1:-1])
            else:
                print(reviews[0][1:-1])
        else:
            print(reviews[0][1:-1])
    else:
        print(reviews[0][1:-1])


for line in data_tup:
    reviews_extractor(line)
```

Is there a better way to do it without putting all this if and else?

Comment: What are you extracting? What is the expected result for each test string?

Comment: Do you want the number after `X.X out of 5 starts`?

Comment: `[stars]` almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does, but we also cannot guess what you hope to do. Can you explain the logic?

Comment: Trivially, `re.findall(r"[stars][\d,]+\$|[s][\W\d,]+[P]|[s][\W\d,]+[i]|[s][\W\d,]+[B]|[s][\W\d,]+[M]", data[1])` picks out the first successful one of these expressions. They could obviously be refactored a great deal (for example, `[B]` and `[M]` could be merged to `[BM]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to extract the number of customer reviews?

```
def reviews_extractor(data):
    # capturing a digit after `stars` e.g. stars5
    print(re.search(r'stars([0-9.,]*)', data[1]).group(1))
```

Comment: This is right imho, although SkylerX also matches the `,`.

Comment: @SimonFink Thank you for letting me know, it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am assuming that each review number starts with keyword "stars" and end with "$"

```
for d in data_tup:
   m = re.compile('stars(.*?)\$', re.DOTALL).search(d[1])                
   f =  m.group(1)    
   output = ''.join(c for c in f if c.isdigit())
   print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number after the number of stars, this regex should work: `"\d(?:.\d)? out of 5 stars(\d+)"`

```py
import re

data_tup = [('B079T2F3CY', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Poster Inspired Watercolor Wall Art Jedi Yoda Death Star Prints Decor Paper Set of 6 8x10 P49 by PGbureau4.8 out of 5 stars16$24.99$24.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates"),
('B01A0NB55A', 'Star Wars Mug, Lightsabers Appear With Heat (12 oz)4.3 out of 5 stars948$9.99$9.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$6.91(2 used & new offers)'),
('B00VF18WWG', 'Star Wars: The Phantom MenaceMPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)|Closed Caption4.2 out of 5 stars3,037Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Liam Neeson,Ewan McGregor,Natalie PortmanandJake LloydDirected by:George LucasRuntime:136 minutes'),
('B00KRIR2HY', "Star Wars Men's Words Of Wisdom T-Shirt4.6 out of 5 stars372$11.00$11.00-$25.99$25.99"),
('B07CFYL578', 'VTech Star Wars First Order Stormtrooper Smartwatch4.2 out of 5 stars191$53.48$53.48Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$30.45(5 used & new offers)Ages: 5 - 9 years'),
('B077T5MG5F', 'Star Wars: The Last Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG-13 (Parents Strongly Cautioned)|Closed Caption3.8 out of 5 stars4,738Prime Videofrom$2.99$2.99to rentStarring:Oscar Isaac,Mark Hamill,Daisy RidleyandJohn BoyegaDirected by:Rian JohnsonRuntime:151 minutes'),
('B079T2F3CY', 'Star Wars Poster Inspired Watercolor Wall Art Jedi Yoda Death Star Prints Decor Paper Set of 6 8x10 P49 by PGbureau4.8 out of 5 stars16$24.99$24.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B00VF0M7QE', 'Star Wars: Return of the Jedi (Theatrical Version)MPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance Suggested)|Closed Caption4.5 out of 5 stars1,055Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Mark Hamill,Harrison Ford,Carrie Fisher, et al.Directed by:Richard MarquandRuntime:134 minutes'),
('B01J5GKX60', 'Star Wars Classic Space Battle Full Sheet Set4.5 out of 5 stars53$34.99$34.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 2 left in stock - order soon.More Buying Choices$26.99(3 new offers)'),
('B079MB31DY', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Enjoy The Wood Star Wars Music Box Wooden Star Wars Fans Custom Gift for Boyfriend Gift for Brother4.9 out of 5 stars22$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates"),
('B00ZYXVU7K', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Lightsaber Heat Change Mug4.1 out of 5 stars158$13.95$13.95Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 9 left in stock - order soon."),
('B014HPF5G2', 'Hasbro Gaming Star Wars Bop It Game4.7 out of 5 stars446$14.99$14.99$16.99$16.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$7.99(16 used & new offers)Ages: 8 years and up'),
('B00VN0DLRA', 'Star Wars: A New HopeMPAA Rating: PG (Parental Guidance  Suggested)|Closed Caption4.5 out of 5 stars2,226Prime Videofrom$19.99$19.99to buyStarring:Mark Hamill,Harrison Ford,Carrie FisherandPeter CushingDirected by:George LucasRuntime:124 minutes'),
('B079MB31DY', 'Enjoy The Wood Star Wars Music Box Wooden Star Wars Fans Custom Gift for Boyfriend Gift for Brother4.9 out of 5 stars22$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B076FDK9TF', 'Lenovo Star Wars: Jedi Challenges, Smartphone Powered Augmented Reality ExperienceDec 1, 2017|by Lenovo4.0 out of 5 stars102iOS$64.99$64.99$99.99$99.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesMore Buying Choices$35.99(35 used & new offers)'),
('B015NFSC24', "Star Wars Classic Logo and Tie Fighter Men's Short Sleeve T-Shirt4.8 out of 5 stars52$15.89$15.89-$19.99$19.99"),
('B013GTX6JI', 'Star Wars - The Complete Saga Episodes I-VI4.5 out of 5 stars6,958Blu-ray$78.49$78.49More Buying Choices$45.99(26 used & new offers)DVD$43.93$43.93In stock on August 30, 2019.More Buying Choices$43.00(11 used & new offers)'),
('B013C1JLLM', 'Star Wars Episode VII Plastic Table Cover, Party Favor4.5 out of 5 stars8More Buying Choices$1.59(16 new offers)Ages: 36 months - 15 years'),
('0440418410', 'The Boys Start the War (Boy/Girl Battle)byPhyllis Reynolds Naylor|Jan 8, 20024.2 out of 5 stars37Paperback$6.99$6.99More Buying Choices$0.10(122 used & new offers)Kindle$6.99$6.99Library Binding$17.80$17.80Only 3 left in stock (more on the way).More Buying Choices$5.62(47 used & new offers)'),
('B00CLS39UM', 'SponsoredThese are ads for products you\'ll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product\'s page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars"Who\'s Your Daddy"? Father\'s Day Coffee Mug Collectible Novelty 11 Oz Nice Valentine Inspirational and Motivational Souvenir4.7 out of 5 stars143$10.99$10.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates'),
('B018SAMUE2', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Grid Mug of Episode VII + 4 Free Bonus The Force Awakens Stickers4.1 out of 5 stars3$14.99$14.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab EmiratesOnly 12 left in stock - order soon."),
('B00O0TE4MC', "SponsoredThese are ads for products you'll find on Amazon.com.Clicking an ad will take you to the product's page.Learn more about Sponsored Products.Star Wars Classic 63” Drapery /Curtain 4pc Set (2 Panels, 2 Tie backs) - R2D2, C3PO, Chewbacca, Darth Vader, Stormtrooper - Official Star Wars Product4.5 out of 5 stars168$13.01$13.01$19.99$19.99Eligible for Shipping to United Arab Emirates")]

for code, text in data_tup:
    print(re.search("\d(?:.\d)? out of 5 stars(\d+)", text).group(1))
```

Regex breakdown:

1. `\d(?:.\d)?`:

   - `\d`: any decimal character (0-9).
   - `(?:.\d)?`: `.\d` means a literal `.` followed by a decimal character (0-9), `(?:   )` tells the regex to group all the characters but not store the substring (so that we can apply the `?` without storing the content), and the last `?` tells that it can be zero times or once.
2. `out of 5 stars`: the exact text.
3. `(\d+)`: `\d` means any decimal character (0-9), `+` means 1 or more of them, and the `()` tell the regex to group all the characters inside and store this substring.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQJgRb/2)

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor bug in @joumaico that if there is a comma after the number then it will give an error. For instance " out of 5 stars948,Prime $9"  will throw an error.

More universally working regex would be:

```
def reviews_extractor(data):
    # Only captures digit, (all length of digits)
    return (re.search(r'stars([0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)', data[1]).group(1))
```